# Converting elements of list into integers

Tags: python, list, loops, type-conversion

I want to take a list that contains smaller lists which contain strings, to convert the strings inside the smaller lists into integers. For example:

```
lst=[["1","2"],["3","4"]]
```

and return

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].
```

This is what I have but it returns the exact same list. I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
 a=0
 for i in lst:
    while a<len(i):
        for j in lst[a]:
            j=int(j)
        a=a+1
 print(lst)
```

Comment: Well you never *change* the list itself, you only construct an `int(j)`, and assign that to `j`.

Comment: You can do this with `[[int(j) for j in row] for row in lst]`.